# how to change startAt value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.memberDesc').click(function(){

    var memberid = $(this).attr('rel').valueOf();
    var memberidNo = parseInt(memberid);
      $('.popupBoxFlexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow:false,
        directionNav:true,
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop:false,
        startAt: memberidNo,
        start: function(slider){
            startAt:memberidNo
        }   
      });
});
```

even with the change in startAt value the flexslider doesnt show that particular li...i think once the flexslider is initialize the startAt value doesnt change.can u help with how to reinitialize it or dynamically change the startAt value

Comment: Is https://github.com/woothemes/flexslider you are using? Always add reference to plugin if you are using it.

Comment: When the page loads, will the slideshow always start with slide #0?
Also, will member IDs always be in perfect consecutive order starting from 0? What if a member leaves?

Comment: I still need to know the answer to the first question, but in general, I think you need to rethink your strategy. Currently, you're trying to recreate the slideshow every time the user clicks on a `.memberDesc` element. You you *want* to do is create the slideshow independently, and then just go to the slide you want when `.memberDesc` is clicked on. Here's a draft example: http://jsfiddle.net/We4GA/

Comment: the example u gave is cool..want somewhat like this but how can i jump to individual names...like on refreshng the page if i click carla there is no movement

Comment: thanks a tonn  Ayman Safadi it worked the way i wanted